# SSRS reporting: aggregates

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate

For one of my SSRS reports I am using this expression:

```
=RunningValue(Code.Calsum("DataSet1",Previous(Fields!DETL_SBSB_ID.Value)
,Fields!DETL_SBSB_ID.Value,Previous(Fields!DETL_CSPI_ID.Value)
,Fields!DETL_CSPI_ID.Value,Fields!DETL_AMT.Value), Sum, "Group7")
```

I am receiving this error:

> the value expression for the text run uses a previous function in an outer aggregate. Previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates

How do I resolve this? I tried using a function for Calsum on the code side.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get a running value of the previous item. Are you trying to get a running value and then subtract the current row? Also, what does `Calsum` do?

Comment: =RunningValue(Iif((RowNumber("DataSet1") = 1) Or (Previous(Fields!DETL_SBSB_ID.Value) <> Fields!DETL_SBSB_ID.Value Or Previous(Fields!DETL_CSPI_ID.Value) <> Fields!DETL_CSPI_ID.Value) Or Fields!DETL_AMT.Value <> 0.00, Fields!DETL_AMT.Value, nothing), Sum, "Group7")

Comment: The above expression was what i had , initially .Replaced it with Calsum function

Comment: Can anyone please help on this ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain what you are trying to do. For example, provide a small sample of data and show the intended result. Also explain the context of your grouping (Group7). The scope of the expression makes a difference.

Comment: Did anyone got the solution for this ?